# Создание собственных меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, добавление-меток

Совсем недавно, при создании вопроса, заметил, что на сайте можно создавать собственные метки.

Мои вопросы:

1. На чём нужно основываться создавая собственную метку?
2. Будет ли какое-то наказание, если создал "некачественную" метку?
3. Если создал метку и она получила голоса и на неё задали много вопросов. Будет ли
   какая-то награда?
4. Сколько меток можно создавать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Стоит подумать, будет ли кто-то создаваемой меткой пользоваться, т. е. подписываться на неё. Можете ли вы представить человека, которому будет интересна 
   [почти] **вся** тема, этой меткой покрываемая. Поэтому полезно иметь однозначную метку, не излишне обобщённую и, естественно, относящуюся к тематике сайта. Это основное.

   Также при создании метки есть смысл сразу отправить правку в её описание (дабы зафиксировать её значение) и следить за тем, что с этой правкой происходит. Это неплохой способ получить первичную обратную связь от сообщества.

---

2. Нет, наказания за плохую метку не будет.

   Если созданная метка полгода будет висеть на единственном вопросе, система сама молча её уничтожит. А если не на одном, то не уничтожит, она продолжит висеть на старых вопросах и никому мешать особо не будет.

   А если меткой будут пользоваться... то виноваты будете уже не вы один! Но не наказывать же всех причастных, верно? Хотя, если вы сами будете развешивать созданную метку на релевантные вопросы... тут уже "серая зона", если это будет мешать людям, могут вмешаться модераторы. Но они тоже к наказаниям не сразу переходят, они сначала сообщают о проблеме, давая вам шанс её не развивать.

---

3. Нет, не будет. По-моему, на SE вообще нет понятия "создатель метки", потому и связанных с этим наград нет никаких. Разве что следуя п. 1 вы можете за правки описаний получить +4 репутации (по +2 за короткое и развернутое).

---

4. Нет, создавайте сколько влезет, если считаете полезным. Если у сообщества мнение будет отличаться, вы об этом вскоре узнаете.

   Могут быть какие-то ограничения на скорость внесения правок (сколько правок в день можно делать), но точной информации об этом я сходу не нашёл. Но он безопасен для вас, это условный "шлагбаум", а не "сторож с заряженным ружьём".

Comment: Награда [есть](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist). С метками связано еще несколько знаков.

Comment: Вопрос: вновь созданную метку можно будет добавить в уже заданные вопросы?